# How do I install app on emulator that gives error with adb

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am running android studio in kali linux.
The image I am using for emulator is `Nexus 5X API 26 with the Android 8.0 (Google APIs)`.
Recently I downloaded an apk file and while installing it with `adb install com.example.main.apk`
It is showing me error as

```
adb: failed to install com.example.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

How to solve this and install the app?
Do I need to download different image for emulator??

Comment: does com.example.main.apk contains native libraries right? if so, is there any x86 version of this native library bundled on it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am completely new to debugging android apps. I started in apk decompiling and testing by mimicking ctf write ups. So far those apps didn't gave me any problem while installing. This is the first one I encounter. So if you know your stuff and guess the possible scenarios that may have happened give suggestion according those. I will try all of those. In the meanwhile I will try to learn about the stuff you said.